# My database is not appearing

Tags: java, android

I created the next database: `encuestadoSQLiteHelper encuestado = new encuestadoSQLiteHelper(this, "DBEncuestado", null, 1);
        final SQLiteDatabase db = encuestado.getWritableDatabase();`

And here:

```
Intent pas = new Intent(encuesta.this, MainActivity.class);
                Toast.makeText(context,"¡Encuesta enviada!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(pas);
                String nombre = "Pablo";
                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Encuestado (nombre) " +
                        "VALUES ('" + nombre +"')");
                db.close();
```

Database is not being created, because i go to documents/sdcard/data/ and my application package don't appears. I need help, thanks!

Comment: Did you tried to fetch data and check if it exists ?, Is you device Rooted ?

Comment: http://facebook.github.io/stetho/ Can put in Stetho to see if you get the data storing inside a SQLite DB.

Comment: What is fetch data. I dont know if my device is rooted.

Answer (score 0):

Database is created, but Database is not accessible for user. it is only accessible for app which created this database.

If you want to access the database then there are two ways, root your phone or write code to copy database from your application to another folder.

**EDIT:**

Copy database from code to Sdcard

```
try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "/data/"+YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME+"/databases/"+DATABASE_NAME;
            String backupDBPath = "backdatabase.sqlite";
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("error in data base copy:"+e);
    }
```

And also you have permission in menifest file for accessing SDCard:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: And what code i have to write for copy database from my app to another folder?

Comment: So, this code: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` Where i have to write it?

Comment: In Menifest file.

Comment: your database name is `DBEncuestado`.

Comment: And my package name is not working it is `package com.example.pablo.myapplication;`, but i write it, and it says "`Expression expected - Rename reference`"

Comment: And also an error with database name "`Cannot resolve symbol 'DBEncuestado`"

Comment: write you package name like "com.example.pablo.myapplication".

Comment: DBEncuestado is also in "DBEncuestado"

Comment: It gives me error, com.example.pablo.myapplication with quotes?

Comment: Use this line:
 String currentDBPath = "/data/com.example.pablo.myapplication/databases/DBEncuestado";

Comment: If you using Android studio then you can see Menifests folder above Java folder. Double click on it. It opens the AndroidMenifest.xml file.

Comment: I wrote that line in androidmanifest, but when i use the app, then i go to my files/storage/sdcard0/Android/data, and i can't find my package! :(

Comment: You can find sdcard0 folder.

Comment: Yes, and then, i can find Android - data, but there is no my package, there is my apps package like `com.spotify.music`, or `com.facebook.lite`, but there is no my package.

Comment: This is my manifest code: `<application><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Resultados" />
        <activity android:name=".encuesta" />
        <activity android:name=".resProfesores" />
        <activity android:name=".res11" />
    </application>`

Comment: don't go to data, just go to sdcard and find filename `backdatabase.sqlite`

Comment: There is no that file, there is just `Download`, `Pictures`, `Android`, `APP`, `DCIM`, `Documents`. Documents is empty.

Comment: That is maybe because i have my sdcard encrypted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to export the file to be accessible in your storage

```
private void exportDB() throws Exception {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                File sd = context.getExternalCacheDir();
                File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
                FileChannel source = null;
                FileChannel destination = null;
                StringBuilder localPath = new StringBuilder();
                localPath.append(context.getExternalCacheDir().toString()).append("/");
                String currentDBPath = "/data/" + YOUR_PACKAGE_HERE + "/databases/" + DATABASE_NAME;
                String backupDBPath = DATABASE_NAME;
                File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
                source = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                destination = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
                source.close();
                destination.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: And i have to do that in other class, or just i can do it in my created class that is `encuesta.java`?

Comment: It can be in the same class, but be sure you have a `context`

Comment: Alright bro, im going to test it. If it works, im going to love you.

Comment: I have this code: `String sql = "CREATE TABLE Encuestado (nombre TEXT)";
    public encuestadoSQLiteHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }` My database name is `Encuestado` or `db` or `sql`?